# Convert JSON with a Parent ID and child array into an array of one json object per element in child array in Dataweave

Tags: dataweave

I need to convert a json array that has objects with a child array into an array of objects with one record (object) per each child array object.

Input:

```
[
  {
    "recId": 1,
    "Attrs": [
      {
        "color": "red",
        "priority": 1
      },
      {
        "color": "purple",
        "priority": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "recId": 2,
    "Attrs": [
      {
        "color": "gold",
        "priority": 3
      },
      {
        "color": "blue",
        "priority": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "recId": 3,
    "Attrs": null
  }
]
```

Desired Output:

```
[
  {
    "recId": 1,
    "color": "red",
    "priority": 1
  },
  {
    "recId": 1,
    "color": "purple",
    "priority": 2
  },
  {
    "recId": 2,
    "color": "gold",
    "priority": 3
  },
  {
    "recId": 2,
    "color": "blue",
    "priority": 2
  }
]
```

I've tried several different things without success.  I can't find any good examples anywhere or documentation. I cannot figure out how to capture the recId and have each object of the Attrs be a separate record.

Answer (score 1):

You could transform/iterate through every item on the Array using **map**. Then take each object in Attrs using another map and **returning the same object plus the recId**.

**This will output an array of array so you need to flatten it** (with the function flatten or using flatMap instead of the first map).

To ignore the null, you could use the writer property **skipNullOn**.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
flatten(payload map ((item, index) -> 
    item.Attrs map ((attr, index) -> 
        {"recId": item.recId} ++ attr
        )
    )
)
```